# Google Cloud Shell is temporarily unavailable

Tags: shell, google-app-engine, google-cloud-shell

I am new to google app engine. Recently I have been using the google cloud console to develop my own blog for a while. However, since last Sunday, I cannot connect to the google cloud shell. Whenever I try to connect to the cloud shell, an error message comes up saying that "Google Cloud Shell is temporarily unavailable. Try connecting in a few minutes." I have tried to restart the shell and re-logout/login but neither of them works. I tried to start the cloud shell under another project but it didn't work either. I have also tried to login in other computers or using other network but still don't work. I have asked a few friends and it seems that I am the only one who have this issue. Here is a link to the screenshot of the issue that I have:

[image: google cloud shell issue]

Does anyone have experience of dealing with this kind of issue? I am really eager to solve this problem because all my code is stored on the cloud code editor which can only be opened when cloud shell is connected. Your help will be really appreciated!

Comment: potentially related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45270850/cloud-shell-temporarily-unavailable

Comment: Somebody else has asked this question before but nobody replies.

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their programming code. Requests for tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for reminding shellter. I guess this question should be asked somewhere else.

Comment: Restart your cloud shell will solve this issue. You can restart by clicking on 3 dots on the right of shell and click restart.

Comment: @khan I tried that lots of times but that didn't work. Fortunately this issue somehow disappeared and never happened again.

Comment: This question is a DUPLICATE of a question asked in another community and has been answered there, so it must be closed here. This is the link https://serverfault.com/questions/865862/google-cloud-shell-is-temporarily-unavailable

Answer (score 3):

just add to the end of the url (&cloudshell=true) and reload the page and it will works !